# Significance of Category name in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone please tell me the significance of category name when we create a category?

I know that the compiler uses this to identify and match the implementations with interfaces. Is there any other use for it?

What if we create 2 categories with different names implementing same method in 2 different ways. Example:

```
@interface NSString(Good)
- (BOOL)isGood;
@end
@implementation NSString(Good)
- (BOOL)isGood
{
return TRUE;
}
@end


@interface NSString(Bad)
- (BOOL)isGood;
@end
@implementation NSString(Bad)
- (BOOL)isGood
{
return FALSE;
}
@end
```

And now in the program I create a string

```
NSString *goodString = @"GOOD";
```

I got the output of `[goodString isGood]` as false.

I want to know why and how the name of category is involved in this?

Comment: I tried switching the position of implementation of the two categories and got it as TRUE.

Some how only the last implemented category got invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to the category names, according to [this article](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories) the only restriction is that they don't conflict with other category names within the same class.

With respect to the categories using the same *method names*, according to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html), it's undefined which method will be called at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever implementation of method with same name "wins" doesn't have anything to do with category names. The "winning" one will be the one loaded *last*, and whichever one will that be isn't known until runtime, because load order is non-deterministic.

Comment: Is there anyway we can purposefully invoke the same method in the category to give two different results in runtime??.
Can we do something to use both these implementations?

Comment: @Gokul, I think that your best bet is to prefix the methods differently between the categories, something that Apple even [recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4).